# How to change content inside table when condition search is false using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a code for table and search text :

```
<div class="table-responsive">
   Search Data : <input type="text" class="txtSearch" id="search_field">
   <div class="tableFixHead">
      <table id="fid_table" class="ui celled table" style="width:100%">
         <thead>
           <tr class="t_head">
             <th>No</th>
             <th>Name</th>
             <th>Gender</th>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>John</td>
             <td>Male</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>Lily</td>
             <td>Female</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>Joe</td>
             <td>Male</td>
           </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I have simple search code using javascript like this :

```
 $('#search_field').on('keyup', function() {
     var value = $(this).val();
     var patt = new RegExp(value, "i");

     $('#fid_table').find('tr').each(function() {
         var $table = $(this);
         var result = $table.find('td').text().search(patt);

         if (!(result >= 0)) {
             $table.not('.t_head').hide();
         }
         if ((result >= 0)) {
             $(this).show();
         }
     });
 });
```

And I want make `$table.not('.t_head').hide()` change to text inside tag `<td>` and make a text like this `Sorry, bla bla bla`.

[image: Before I input text on search field]

Before I input text on search field

[image: After I input and the result is false]

After I input and the result is false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the whole table body to search for the text, so if it returns `-1` you could use it to negate and toggle the element that shows the message ( I have placed it as an additional row, that is hidden on load) about no results.

Also, you could use a `.toggle()`, instead of the conditional block to simplify the code and constrain the selection to the `tbody` of the table element, to avoid filtering the `thead` of the table element.

And finally, use the jQuery's `.filter()` to iterate through selection and return only those that fulfill the conditions:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 var tableRows = $('#fid_table tbody tr');
 var table = $('#fid_table tbody');
 var noResults = $('.no-results');
 noResults.hide();
 
$('#search_field').on('keyup', function() {

     var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
     var patt = new RegExp(value, "i");
    
    tableRows.filter(function() {
      var toggle = $(this).text().toLowerCase().search(patt) > -1;
      $(this).toggle(toggle );
    });
    
    var noResultsToggle = table.text().toLowerCase().search(patt) === -1;
    noResults.toggle(noResultsToggle);
 
   
 });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive">
   Search Data : <input type="text" class="txtSearch" id="search_field">
   <div class="tableFixHead">
      <table id="fid_table" class="ui celled table" style="width:100%">
         <thead>
           <tr class="t_head">
             <th>No</th>
             <th>Name</th>
             <th>Gender</th>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>John</td>
             <td>Male</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>Lily</td>
             <td>Female</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>Joe</td>
             <td>Male</td>
           </tr>
           
         </tbody>
         <tfoot>
             <tr class="no-results">
              <td colspan="3" align="center">
               Sorry, there are no results for given search string
               </td>
           </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can have an element with the message. Show/hide that element based on the condition:

Try the following way:

```js
$('#search_field').on('keyup', function() {
     var value = $(this).val();
     var patt = new RegExp(value, "i");

     $('#fid_table').find('tr').each(function() {
         var $table = $(this);
         var result = $table.find('td').text().search(patt);

         if (!(result >= 0)) {
             $table.hide();
             $('#message').show()
         }
         else if((result >= 0)) {
             $('#message').hide();
             $(this).show();
         }
     });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive">
   Search Data : <input type="text" class="txtSearch" id="search_field">
   <div class="tableFixHead">
      <div id="message" style="display:none">Sorry, no data!</div>
      <table id="fid_table" class="ui celled table" style="width:100%">
         <thead>
           <tr class="t_head">
             <th>No</th>
             <th>Name</th>
             <th>Gender</th>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>John</td>
             <td>Male</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>Lily</td>
             <td>Female</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>Joe</td>
             <td>Male</td>
           </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
</div>
```